# Prevent Adium logout when locking screen on OSX 10.8.2

Tags: macos, screen-lock, adium

Since upgrading to OSX 10.8.2 from 10.6.x I find that when I lock the screen Adium logs out. Upon unlocking screen Adium logs back in.

It used to just set to away when screen locked and I have pushover scripts that rely on this.

How can I get it to behave the way it did before I upgraded?

Comment: My Adium still sets away when I lock the computer, this is with OSX 10.8.2 and Adium 1.5.4. I didn't have to change any settings when upgrading from 10.6.X. Which service(s) are you using Adium for? I only use MSN Messenger.

Comment: Ok, well that's good to hear. I'm using Adium for a number of accounts on various IM services. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is determined by the settings in the Status pane of Adium preferences.  Specifically, it's determined by the "When Screen Saver is activated, set:" preference.  Check to make sure that's not set to "Offline".

[image: Adium status preference pane]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of "Wake on Demand" feature in OSX 10.8. Details here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774

To disable:
Go to System Prefs -> Energy Saver, on the 'Power Adapter' page, uncheck the 'Wake for network access' box.

Comment: This doesn't make any difference for me.